# Flask set @app decorator outside main module

Tags: flask

How do you set an `@app...` decorator outside of the main module?

I'm sorry if this a dumb question, but I am completely lost.

I wish to be able to decorate functions with `@app.context_processor` all over the place in a larg-ish app.  All the examples I can find have these in main module, where `app` is defined.  Thus in `main.py` I have e.g.

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app()

@app.context_processor
def test_me():
    return {'test_me': 'test_me!!!'}
```

and in `__init__.py` I have

```
def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    return app
```

That's fine, but how do I do same in some other module?  `app` is not defined.

Let's say I have just that `def test_me()` in some other module.  The module (presently) has no `import`s, doesn't use blueprints, etc.

Most questions asking about "how to access app in another module" use `from flask import current_app`, but you can only use `current_app` during a request, such as inside a `def`.  Attempting to somehow use it for a decorator will give you the "not available in this context`, so that's not the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question.

I needed to move the

```
app = create_app()
```

out of `main.py` and into `__init__.py`.  Then `app` is visible to every module, and each one can go

```
from app import app

@app.context_processor
def something():
    return {'something': 'something'}
```